# 'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, oracle, command-prompt

I wanted to work on OracleDb using Python hence I've installed `pip install cx_Oracle`. The entire time when I was working on it, everything went fine but after sometime when again I wanted to open cx_Oracle it showed this error:

> 'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Then I went on to uninstall it:

```
C:\Users\PRATIKBAWANE>pip uninstall cx_Oracle
Found existing installation: cx-Oracle 8.3.0
Uninstalling cx-Oracle-8.3.0:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\pratikbawane\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\cx_oracle-doc\license.txt
    c:\users\pratikbawane\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\cx_oracle-doc\readme.txt
    c:\users\pratikbawane\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\cx_oracle-8.3.0.dist-info\*
    c:\users\pratikbawane\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\cx_oracle.cp310-win_amd64.pyd
Proceed (Y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled cx-Oracle-8.3.0
```

And again tried to install it:

```
C:\Users\PRATIKBAWANE>pip install cx_Oracle
Collecting cx_Oracle
  Using cached cx_Oracle-8.3.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (213 kB)
Installing collected packages: cx-Oracle
Successfully installed cx-Oracle-8.3.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\PRATIKBAWANE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\PRATIKBAWANE>import cx_Oracle
'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Then why even after the Successful installation it is showing error:

> 'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

I'm not getting it can somebody explain it to me so that whenever it happens atleast I may have the reason for it.
Thank You so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running `import cx_Oracle` in a Windows command line, not in a Python interpreter. You need to launch Python first, something like this:

```
C:\Users\PRATIKBAWANE>python
Python 3.9.9 (main, Dec 13 2021, 17:45:33) 
[GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cx_Oracle
>>>
```

`python` may have a different name in Windows cmd, like `python3` or `py`. If none of these work, you need to check if Python is "added to PATH" (google it)

Answer (score 0):

Why are your writing it in terminal? Import is not terminal command but python one. You should run python first in your terminal, open its interpreter and write python code. Or just write python code in editor and compile it in terminal.

Comment: Just saw it's actually windows command prompt but same thing as linux terminal. My point still stands.

Comment: Thank You so much! I appreciate your effort.

Comment: No problem :) Good luck!